# QLineEdit: how to put cursor at the end of typed text?

Tags: c++, qt

There is a QLineEdit in which you need to enter a phone number. Gave him a mask

```
ui->lineEdit_4->setInputMask("+7\\(999\\)999\\-99\\-99;_");
```

Further, when saving the data, the entered string is checked by the validator:

```
QRegularExpression numberRegex ("^\\+\\d{1,1}\\(\\d{3,3}\\)\\d{3,3}\\-\\d{2,2}\\-\\d{2,2}$");
QRegularExpressionValidator *numberValidator = new QRegularExpressionValidator (numberRegex);
QString a = ui->lineEdit_4->text();
int b = ui->lineEdit_4->cursorPosition();
if(numberValidator->validate(a, b) == QValidator::Acceptable){
....
}
```

Above I described everything that is, and now the very essence of the problem. Typing is extremely inconvenient, since the cursor is not attached to anything. Wherever you click, the cursor will appear there. How to make the cursor appear where you need to type text? So far, in ideas there is only a check for the cursor position, and every time it changes, put it on the first "_" in the line. But something sounds crazy

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean "disable moving cursor and force it to be at the end of the field always", "disable moving cursor by mouse, but using cursor keys is fine", "remove visible cursor and just have user typing appear at the end" or what?

Comment: Overriding [`QWidget::mousePressEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) may be an option.

Comment: @hyde It is necessary that when you click the mouse, the cursor always goes to the end of the typed text.

Answer (score 1):

Connect this signal: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#cursorPositionChanged

In the target method, move cursor to the end of the field with this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#end

Something like this:

```
QObject::connect(
    ui->lineEdit_4,
    &QLineEdit::cursorPositionChanged,
    this,
    [this](){
        ui->lineEdit_4->end(false);
    });
```

Comment: Note: untested, if you try this and it doesn't work or needs fixing, please tell.

Comment: Thats working good, but i have mask in my lineedit (put it in the body of the question). I have _  symbol  in empty spaces to be filled. You can, of course, cycle through the line and put the cursor on the first "_" in the text, but I think there is a more competent solution

Comment: I tried my theory with looping through - no luck. I can get the cursor position, let's say it will be equal to 10. But I can't check what is in the line at this position - because of the specified mask, the line (lineEdit->text()) is equal to everything except "_"

Comment: @Mainquestion I'm not sure I understand your problem fully, but I'd consider not using Qt validator at all, instead doing your own checks when ever user enters text or moves the cursor.